# Logging API Request/response with Xero API java

Tags: xero-api

We are integrating XERO API's with Xero-java SDK. We have a requirement to intercept requests/responses posted to XERO. Essentially we need to do a audit trail log.

How to do this with Xero-SDK java?

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't any logging built into Xero's Java SDK.  You are welcome to fork and make a PR on Github.

https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-Java

I recommend adding a boolean flag to JsonConfig.java to the logging feature can be turned on/off by developers.

Comment: We added support for log4j in version 1.0.0 of our Java SDK.

https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-Java#logging